# See POST parameters in Java EE eclipse debugging

Tags: java, post, debugging

I'm not experienced in debugging Java EE (I'm rather a javascript guy) and I need to see what HTTP POST parameters get to the server side. I put a breakpoint in a jsp file that the form is pointing its action to and now I can't find the POST content in the debug variables window.

Where are they? How can I lookup the POST in debug?

[I'd use wireshark, but it's over the https]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the breakpoint, just check the `HttpServletRequest` property of the `JspContext` instance and then check its `parameterMap` property.

Or do it the poor man's way by just printing them all in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${param}" var="p">
    Param: ${p.key}=
    <c:forEach items="${p.value}" var="v" varStatus="loop">
        ${v}${loop.last ? '<br>' : ','}
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

That said, you'd normally be interested in them inside a servlet class, not inside a JSP. This would indicate that you're doing some business logic inside a JSP file using using *scriptlets*. This is considered bad practice. Don't do that and move that raw Java code  to real Java classes before it's too late. Use JSP for presentation only. You can use taglibs like JSTL to control the page flow and use EL to access backend data.

Comment: "This is considered bad practice" - nope, this is called "not my code" :D 

Thanx for the answer. I won't check it out now, because I did it with a workaround, and it's over now ;)

Answer (score 4):

In jsp you can use `request` object and call its method `getParameterNames ()` or `getParameter (String name)`. You can also call `request.getMethod ()` to ensure that you obtain parameters from POST request.

```
<%
   if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
      for (String paramName : request.getParameterNames ()) {
          String value = request.getParameter (paramName);
      }
   }
%>
```

Comment: java says request.getParameterNames() is not ok to iterate on

Answer (score 3):

In debug mode: see
request -> request -> coyoteRequest -> parameters -> paramHashValues

Comment: This is the information I wanted. Thank you for this list.