# request parameters values in Eclipse Luna debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

How Can I see the request parameters values in Eclipse Luna debugger ?

Answer (score 9):

To drill down using the debugger variables tab:
request -> request -> coyoteRequest -> parameters -> paramHashValues

Answer (score 1):

You could drill down into the request object's parameters using the debugger's `Variables` tab. However, in this case it's easier to use the `Expressions` tab to execute code on the request object.

1. Right click the request variable in the Variables tab (Debug perspective) and choose *inspect*
2. It opens a new tab called Expressions. Click *Add new expression*
3. Type `request.getParameter("nameYouCareAbout")`
4. Tab

If you must drill down into the request object, take a look at [how some other people are doing it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356047/see-post-parameters-in-java-ee-eclipse-debugging). To see the parameter values directly in the debugger, be aware [the request object you see is usually a wrapper or facade](http://www.coderanch.com/t/625728/Servlets/java/posted-parameters-eclipse-debugger-variable) so you first have to drill down to the real request. The name of the instance variable is something like `parameters` or `parameterMap`.

Comment: thanks man i try the `Expressions ` tab and it work but i want find it in the `Variables ` tab if it's possible because there a lot of object in the request.

Comment: The request object you see is usually a wrapper or facade so you first have to drill down to the real request. The name of the instance variable is usually `parameters` or `parameterMap`.

Comment: i looked for `parameterMap` but i find a lot of object. andyour solution work but it's not practice in my case because i have a lot of request parameter